# How to update a C/C++ struct with compatibility

Tags: c++, c, casting, compatibility

I have a `struct` defined in a historical library with alas, an unfortunate choice of type: `unsigned char *` instead of `char*`.

```
struct MyStruct {

  unsigned char * myMember;
};
```

This `struct` is used by a huge number of C applications and, more and more, by C++ applications. Those C++ applications raise an error when used with `strlen`, for example, forcing us to cast. Lots of casts.

I would like to remedy that.

But one thing is extremely important: it must be absolutely compatible without modification and have no impact on the existing projects.

I thought about making a `union`. Alas, my variable can't have the same name.

```
struct MyStruct {

  union {
    unsigned char * myMember;
    // char * myMember; Obvioulsy, rejected by the compiler.
};
```

I'm afraid there isn't any obvious solution. Am I wrong?

I can't change the size of the struct because it's mapped in an unchangeable sized shared memory.

Comment: Have you tried std::strlen() ??

Comment: in case `char` is unsigned you might get away with simply removing `unsigned`

Comment: If you can change `MyStruct`, why not just remove `unsigned` as @largest_prime_is_463035818 suggests?

Comment: When talking about compatibility it would be nice to know how your struct is used.

Comment: The idea of changing the type of the variable scares me a lot. Suppose that in an existing C project, this variable is used as an unsigned char *. There is a design error behind it but let's imagine. And having changed the type means that it no longer compile, even if the modification would be minimal. I will be fired :(

Comment: Basically you are asking to change the code and not change the code. There's no solution. If you decide it's better going forward to make the change, then you have to accept that there is some risk. My preferred method would be to change `myMember` to some other name along with the change of type. This will force you to examine each and every use of the name, and make the appropriate change.

Answer (score 10):

Note: You *can't* solve this in C++, because strict C doesn't like `unsigned char*` either. Even with lax C compiler settings, you'd get (example with gcc default settings):

> pointer targets in assignment differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]|

even when doing something basic such as simple assignment `ms.myMember="hello";`.

Here is a C11 solution.

```
struct MyStruct {
  union // anonymous union
  {
    unsigned char * myMember;
    char* myCharMember;
  };
};  

#define myMember myCharMember
```

Test code:

```
struct MyStruct ms;  
_Generic(ms.myMember, 
         char*:           puts("I'm a char*"), 
         unsigned char*:  puts("I'm an unsigned char*"));
```

Without the `#define` and it will tell you `"I'm an unsigned char*"`, but with the `#define`, `"I'm a char*"`.

Comment: Unless C++'s dysfunctional union type punning rules screw up this solution, it should work in C and C++ both. Otherwise, well, file a DR to the C++ committee about the type punning rules... The macro means that the actual `myMember` is never actually used though, so that should dodge union type punning.

Comment: Are you suggesting defining only where the signedness is required? That would indeed be UB in C++, and would break ABI as well.

Comment: @PasserBy The define would sit together with the struct definition, likely in a header. So that it would be impossible to use the struct without the macro present.

Comment: I'm confused, then how is this different than simply changing the type?

Comment: @PasserBy If changing the type is an option, then do that obviously. But in case the header can't be changed, you could also put the `#define` in a "wrapper header" which in turn includes the old header.

Comment: I'm inclined to suppose that the reason the OP does not simply change the data type of the existing member is that it would cause other, similar issues with different client code, possibly in some of the same translation units.  If some code wants the type to be `char *` and other code in the same TU wants it to be `unsigned char *`, then probably the only viable solutions are to change the code to have a consistent expectation for the data type or to convert the data where needed.

Answer (score 8):

There is a simpler remedy. Often, when you are annoyed by having to do something too many times, it can simply be solved by doing that thing once within a function:

```
std::size_t unsigned_strlen(const unsigned char* str) noexcept
{
    return std::strlen(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(str));
}
```

Comment: The C consumers don't need any solution since they can use `strlen` directly thanks to implicit conversions that the language allows.

Comment: Is it not possible to just provide an override for `std::strlen()` that takes a `const unsigned char*` argument and use the same body as your given function? Or is overriding the standard library frowned-upon?

Comment: @AdrianMole Adding functions to `std` namespace is not allowed.

Comment: OK - didn't know that (never tried). Although you could provide the override without the explicit `std::` namespace prefix?

Comment: You'd have to do this for _all_ string handling functions not just strlen. Quite tedious.

Comment: @AdrianMole `you could provide the override without the explicit std:: namespace prefix?` `strlen` is a reserved name in the global namespace too so I don't think you could overload it there either. What you could do is `using std::strlen;` within a custom namespace, define the overload in that namespace and have the overloading of unqualified `strlen` work as long as you use it in that namespace.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way you can make the `myMember` be a `char*` or any other type without potentially breaking existing projects, for the simple reason that its type can be deduced

```cpp
void foo(decltype(MyStruct::myMember));
```

This will cause ABI issues, the mildest of which is a linker error.

The half measure is to provide a shorthand for the cast

```cpp
struct MyStruct
{
#ifdef __cplusplus
   char* signed_myMember() { return (char*)myMember; }
#endif
};
```

Fortunately, `char` is allowed to alias anything in C++, making this legal.

Comment: Also, signed and unsigned variants of the same underlying integral type are allowed to alias each other.

Answer (score 2):

Given your goal is to create an island of perfection and not fix the world, you could create an adapter with an [implicit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) constructor from this old struct and use that adapter in the "island of perfection" code.

```
struct BetterMyStruct {
  char* myMember;
  
  BetterMyStruct(MyStruct const& x): myMember((char*)x.myMember) {
    // any ugly secret hacks you want or need
  }

};

...

size_t better_strlen(BetterMyStruct const& x) {
  // perfect function
  return std::string_view(x.myMember).size();
}

...

better_strlen(MyStruct(...)); // perfect function invocation on imperfect inputs
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are allowed to change `MyStruct` I suggest just removing `unsigned` which would break the existing ABI and require recompilation of everything using the struct.

If that's not an option for some reason, you could inherit the original struct and provide a getter method for the C++ applications.

```
// use this in C apps
struct MyStruct {
    unsigned char* myMember;
};

// use this in C++ apps
struct MyStructCpp : MyStruct {
    MyStructCpp(const MyStruct& rhs) : MyStruct(rhs) {}
    char* myMemberAsChar() const { return reinterpret_cast<char*>(myMember); }    
};
```

Comment: Might also be useful to make `MyStructCpp` (implicitly?) constructible from  `MyStruct`.

Comment: @eerorika Indeed!  Added!

Comment: @TedLyngmo I added an explanation to my answer (pasted the wrong message in my comment here, sorry). The problem is that you need to make it compile clean in C and C++ both.

Comment: Definitely don't _" just removing unsigned"_, this will cause ABI problems.

Comment: @Lundin No problem. I'll have to re-read what you wrote since I don't see how the added C++ class would interfere with the existing C code.

Comment: @PasserBy "_I have a struct defined in an historical library with alas, an unfortunate choice of type:_" implies that it's time for an ABI breaking change :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo The prerequisite is compatibility, I would at least mention this can cause ABI problems.